# Speaker Labeling is not consistent?? even if it is only 2 speaker

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text, android-sdk-tools

When i try in the demo transcribing audio to text is so accurate this is the output in the demo

```
Speaker 0:
Hello.
Speaker 1:
Hi is this Tina.
Speaker 0:
Yes it is who is this.
```

this is my output

```
Speaker 0:
Hello.
Speaker 1:
Hi is this Tina.
Speaker 0:
Yes it is this this
```

this is my set up in recognize

```
private RecognizeOptions getRecognizeOptions(InputStream captureStream) {
return new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
.audio(captureStream)
.contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_MP3)
.model("en-US_NarrowbandModel")
.interimResults(true)
.inactivityTimeout(-1)
.timestamps(true)
.speakerLabels(true)
.smartFormatting(true)
.build();
}
```

when i trying to change the model into a en-US_Broadband this the output

```
Speaker 0:
Hello.
Speaker 1:
Hi is this Tina. Yes it is who is this
```

The diferrence is the word Yes it is who is this is a different speaker so the expected result will be this

```
Speaker 0:
Hello.
Speaker 1:
Hi is this Tina.
Speaker 0:
Yes it is who is this.
```

please help is this bug or there is something error on my code by the way i am using mp3 file not wav file

Answer (score 1):

What you are discovering is that the sampling rate for the audio is significant when transcribing.

From the documentation - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/index.html#about

> Use broadband for audio that is sampled at a minimum rate of 16 kHz.
>   Use narrowband for audio that is sampled at a minimum rate of 8 kHz.

Consequently audio that is sampled at 8kHz is not going to be as well transcribed when using a broadband model.

Comment: thank you sir you solved my problem but there is another one sir how can i display speaker labels?? in android when i trying to display the speaker is not consistent but the result in logs is consistent please help sir

Comment: That is a different question. Please raise a new question in this forum. Remember to add a snippet of the response that you are trying to process and the code that you are using to process it.